# Geometric circle application

Tags: geometry, circles

A semicircular region of water within 1 mile of a point *O* on shore is restricted. Two warning lights *A* and *B* are placed at 1 mile away on either side of *O* on shore. Describe a simple method of sighting that could be used by a ship S to stay out of the restricted area.
[image: Figure of restricted area]

Comment: What have you tried, and please clarify what the ship can use for measurements (angles, distances). And clean up the formatting (giant space under picture).

Answer (score 1):

As long as the angle $\angle ASB$ is less than $ 90$ degrees the ship is outside the restricted area.

The angle passes through $90$ degrees as it enters the restricted region.

Inside  the region the angle is larger than $90$ degrees.